# CakePHP - POST call to REST API returning null

Tags: json, cakephp, rest, cakephp-1.3

I have set up REST for my CakePHP and I'm having a slight problem. When calling a GET method, like view or index on my controller, or even a custom method that is GET I have no problem getting an answer. But when I try to do a POST action like add I get no output from the operation even though I can see that it reached it correctly and executed (saved to the DB).

I have properly set up the layout file for JSON and XML output as well as the routing and the view for each output type.

EDIT:

Relevant code in `beforeFilter` in `AppController`:

```
      if ( $this->RequestHandler->isAjax() ) {
        $this->layout = 'ajax';
        $this->autoRender = false;
      } elseif  ($this->RequestHandler->isXml()) {
        $this->layout = 'default'; 
        $this->RequestHandler->respondAs('xml');
        $this->RequestHandler->renderAs($this, 'xml');
      } elseif ($this->RequestHandler->ext == 'json') { 
        $this->layout = 'default';
        $this->RequestHandler->respondAs('json');
        $this->RequestHandler->renderAs($this, 'json');
      } elseif ($this->RequestHandler->accepts('html')) {
        $this->layout = 'frontend'; 
      }
```

Code in Routes:

```
Router::mapResources('fonykers');
Router::mapResources('voicenotes');
Router::parseExtensions();
```

Relevant code in my `add` method in `FonykersController`:

```
$response = array('ok' => true, 'title' => 'Thank you for registering', 'msg' => 'A confirmation email has been sent to the provided email address, please click on the link in the email to complete the registration process');
if ($this->RequestHandler->isXml()) {
  $this->set(compact('response'));
} else if ($this->RequestHandler->ext == 'json') {
  pr('This prints');
  $this->set(compact('response')); //View not being outputted
  pr('This also prints');
} else {
  echo json_encode($response); 
}
```

My view in `/views/fonykers/json`

```
<?php echo json_encode(array('response' => $response)); ?>
```

My layout file for json:

```
<?php 
header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, max-age=0, must-revalidate"); 
header('Content-Type: application/json'); 
header("X-JSON: ".$content_for_layout); 
echo $content_for_layout; 
?>
```

Comment: It impossible to say anything without seeing the relevant code.

Comment: Updated my question with relevant code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few things going on...

Your beforeFilter checks for isAjax and then uses `elseif` to test for XML or JSON.  If your request is AJAX, it will never get to the XML/JSON tests.  Your layout is likely not being set at all which leaves you with just `$this->autoRender = false;`.

Since autoRender is disabled, at some point you'll have to manually invoke rendering.  Using `$this->set()` just prepares variables for usage in your view - it doesn't actually output the view.  In your controller action, the only line that would actually output anything is `echo json_encode($response);`.

Use `$this->render()` to force Cake to render the view when you want it to.  More info in [The 1.3 Book: Rendering a specific view](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1648/Rendering-a-specific-view)

---

As an aside, sometimes you use `...}elseif(...` and sometimes you use `...}else if(...`.  This isn't technically wrong, but being consistent will make your code easier to read.

Comment: Thank you Farray, I'll give it a try and let you know. I've checked previously what you stated about the autoRender being false and it's not happening in this case, the calls to my API are made from an iOS device atm and the proper layout and render state are set, it's not hitting the AJAX part because it's not an AJAX call. So seeing that it's still not explained why it's not rendering the view.

Comment: Ok, the this render worked, seeing what I said before is there any other reason why it isn't rendering? My other API calls render and they are made in the same fashion as this one.

Comment: @8vius Sorry, I misunderstood that part of your question and thought it wasn't working with AJAX methods.  Will put some more thought into this later.

Comment: Honest mistake, I appreciate it anyways since it led to a solution (even if it's not the most appropriate one). I'll leave the question open for now.